# Complex differentiability of a specific function

Tags: matrices, complex-analysis, derivatives

Let $f,g:\mathbb R\rightarrow\mathbb R$ with $f(x,y)=(x^2y-\frac{1}{3}y^3,\frac{1}{3}x^3-xy^2)$ and $g=f\circ f$. I have to check wether the complex functions $F(x+iy)=f_1(x,y)+if_2(x,y)$ and $G(x+iy)=g_1(x,y)+ig_2(x,y)$ are complex differentiable or not. I have shown that $f$ is partially differentiable and that the derviatives are continuous, so $f$ is totally differentiable. Therefore, it's total derivative $Df(x,y)$ has a corresponding Jacobi-matrix
$$
        \begin{pmatrix}
        2xy & x^2-y^2 \\
        x^2-y^2 & -2xy\\
        \end{pmatrix}
$$

From this matrix, it follows that the partial derivatives of $f$, and therefore of $F$, do not satisfy the Cauchy-Riemann equations (CRE), so $F$ is not complex differentiable.

Now notice that the problem would be very easy to solve if the partial derivatives of $F$ would satisfy CRE, therefore I was wondering if there are any computational or arrangement issues in my Jacobi-matrix.

Next, if $F$ would satisfy CRE, as mentioned before, it would be quite easy to show that $G$ is complex differentiable. Since I am not convinced that it does, my next question is how I could show that $G$ is complex differentiable in some "clever" way, without having to compute the whole function of $g$ and it's partial derivatives in terms of $x$ and $y$. Just nothing *too* smart, this is from my first complex analysis course.

Any help or insight would be appreciated!

EDIT:

At first I thought that $f$ actually was complex differentiable, because I thought that I had shown that the image corresponding to my Jacobi-matrix is complex-linear. But now I am very confused about what it actually means for an image to be complex-linear in terms of it's corresponding matrix, if it has one. Any help on (understanding) this matter would be very much appreciated as well!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT:  Note that, for example, $g_1(x,y) = f_1(f_1(x,y),f_2(x,y))$.  Using this, try writing out the matrix $Dg$ using the chain rule.  Note that derivatives of the form $\partial{g_i}/\partial{f_j}$ ($i,j = 1,2$) can be obtained very simply from knowing $Df$.

This isn't *much* simpler than brute-forcing the answer, but it's perhaps a bit more elegant and perhaps gives a hint as to why or why not $g$ is complex-differentiable.

Comment: Actually, your hint towards the usage of the chain rule led me to a quite quick and straightforward method to solve this problem. Now I just hope my solution is correct. Much appreciated!